# Numerical Integral Approximation with OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have some C OpenMP code that approximates the integral of sin(x)+1 using the midpoint rule. The code works when I have either one or two threads, however when I get above two threads the approximations are incorrect. Below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main(){
int numPartitions = 10;
double interval = 0, integral = 0, a = 0, b = 0;
int i = 0, j = 0, tid=0; 
interval=5*M_PI/(double)numPartitions;
double start = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
    #pragma omp for firstprivate(b,a,tid) reduction(+:integral)
            for (i = 0; i < numPartitions; i++) 
            {
                tid=omp_get_thread_num();
                b = a;
                a = a+interval;
                integral += ((sin(((b+a)/2))+1)*(interval));   
            }
     }
double end = omp_get_wtime();
printf("Estimate of integral is: %10.8lf\n", integral);
printf("Time=%lf\n", end-start);
return 0;
```

}

Any insight on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.
-Thanks

Comment: All iterations of the parallel loop start with the same value of `a`, equal to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

With your code you need b and a to get right values for all threads.

> b = i * interval;
>
> a = b + interval;

Also, you introduce a extra flop while calculating integral

> **integral += ((sin(((b+a)/2))+1)*(interval));**
>
> change to integral += sin((b+a)/2) + 1.0;
>
> After the for loop
>
> integral *= interval;